# why my pyinstaller display: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position

Tags: python, decode

I am trying pick my `.py` to `.exe` using `pyinstaller`, but some happened. Like this,

> ```
> > 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 121: invalid
> > continuation byte These are the bytes around the offending byte:
> ```

and

> ```
>  File "c:\users\demo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py",
> ```
>
> line 580, in exec_python
>           return exec_command(*cmdargs, **kwargs)
>         File "c:\users\demo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py",
>   line 370, in exec_command
>           out = out.decode(encoding)
>       UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 121: invalid continuation byte

Comment: using anaconda3-4.2.0 ,  win10 , python3.5

Comment: Try to add  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  at the top of your .py file